# Start a batch shell within a bash shell with autocomplete with windows

Tags: windows, bash, ssh, batch, autocomplete

I am using bash inside Cygwin and I want to start a new batch shell within the current shell.

So I use `cmd` to enter into a new batch shell:

```
myuser@machine /
$ cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\cygwin64>
```

So far so good, but then I press `tab` and I don't get autocomplete, instead I get 4 space(   ).

I tried a similar setup with tmux, but couldn't get it working.

Also, I don't want to use an another console such as ConEmu, because I will use ssh to connect to my machine as well.

Comment: Auto complete is not done by the console; It is done by the shell. In addition `bash` can not auto complete for `cmd`. So you have to enable auto complete in `cmd`. Note also: Auto complete in `cmd` is broken, it will more often than not complete what you do not want, pressing tab again has another go, but then you will decide to do it your self, and spend more time deleting the completion than what it saved you.

Comment: That is not absolutely true. Yes, some shells implement their self tab-completion. But if shell uses [ReadConsole](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684958.aspx) function, the completion is done by console (or conhost.exe if you wish). cmd.exe uses ReadConsole.

Answer (score 0):

If by "using bash inside Cygwin" you mean in fact "run bash inside mintty", you will not get proper behavior of "real console" applications at all. You will be able to run properly only "cygwin applications" in this terminal. That is [by desing](https://conemu.github.io/en/CygwinMsys.html).

tmux is not a terminal, it runs another console application (like bash), but it uses the same terminal as you started first. So you'll be bumped into the same problem even if you manage to run tmux.

So, the only solution is using another terminal. And it's completely incomprehensible why you can't run ssh in ConEmu. You may even run [mintty in ConEmu](http://conemu.github.io/en/ChildGui.html) if you really want it.

Also. There is [clink](http://mridgers.github.io/clink/) extension for cmd, which gives to used to unix users habitual tab completion. You may try [cmder](https://github.com/Stanzilla/cmder/releases) which is a bundle of [ConEmu](http://conemu.github.io/en/), clink and some other tools.

Comment: I tried to run ConEmu(starting a new dialog console with a bash shell[from CygWin] or the batch shell[from windows] lead to the same result). Now, let's say I run sshd on my local windows machine(using either openssh from cygwin, or mobassh or copssh). Then with ConEmu, I login through ssh using `ssh myuser@localhost`, I'll be prompted with a new bash shell from the ssh service. From this new bash shell, if I start `cmd`, well the new batch shell is completely broken(tab and arrow keys aren't recognized correctly). Also running `clink_x64.exe inject` didn't fix anything on that batch shell.